# Разница между h5 и hdf5

Tags: форматы-файлов

В чем заключается разница между этими расширениями?

Comment: а где Вы взяли эти форматы?

Comment: @KoVadim https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“.h5” - это расширение в имени файла, используемое для файлов формата HDF5. Это как “.py” для Python скриптов или “.docx” для файлов MS Word.

Comment: Наверное, в вопросе спутал слова "формат" и "расширение". Имелось ввиду, в чем разница между .h5 и .hdf5?

Comment: По-моему, стандартно используется “.h5”, но в принципе файл можно назвать как угодно...